# Debian 9 and RStudio

Tags: debian, software-installation, package-management, r, rstudio

I just switched to Debian following the recent release of version 9. I do a lot of work with RStudio and thus tried to install the stable and testing versions which both failed due to the missing library "libgstreamer0.10-0". It appears that a more recent version of that package is installed but 0.10-0 is not available in stretch. Is there a way to install RStudio despite the missing package? 
Help is much appreciated. Apologies if this is not the right place to ask this question.

OS: Debian 9
RStudio: 1.0.143-amd64

Edit:

Installation was performed using gdebi.

Edit 2:

After installing `libgstreamer0.10` and `libgstreamer-base-0.10` as described in the linked question I now get `libssl1.0.0` as a not satisfiable dependency in gdebi.

Edit 3:

Get lissl1.0.0 from [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libssl1.0.0/download) and install. After that Rstudio installs and runs fine (I'll report back if I encounter problems).

Comment: What is your Rstudio version? - - Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43586708/54964

Comment: Please, describe how you installed RStudio. I think I have had this problem before and there is a solution to it.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest deb package from their website and tried to install it using gdebi. It said that the dependencies could not be met naming the above-mentioned package.

Comment: I tried the accepted solution of the question you linked. That seems to satisfy the libgstreamer situation but now it requires ```libssl1.0.0``` which seems to be ```libssl1.0.2``` in stretch. At this point I think I'll just wait until Rstudio gets updated to not depend out of date software. I'm not super comfortable installing and holding a lot of libraries I don't fully understand.

Comment: Yes, that should also be an easy problem with `libssl1.0.0`, since I think I have had it too. RStudio is already well updated and should work fine in your system too. Please, do not leave this thread a stub. - - Please, provide me the logs what you get now with `libssl...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think RStudio 1.0.143 is sufficient for Debian 9. You just have to fix a few packges there. Do and please report us what you get from step (2)

1. Fix `libgstreamer0.10-0` problem as described in the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413323/rstudio-install-on-ubuntu-16-10-fails-due-to-libgstreamer/43586708#43586708)
2. Fix `libssl1.0.0` problem.

   Download libssl1.0.0 from [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/libssl1.0.0/download)
3. Install libssl1.0.0, install Rstudio
4. Enjoy Rstudio ;)

Comment: edited question

Comment: @DanielWinkler Can you provide a complete log? - - I really have had the same error with `libssl1.0.0` and it is a direct fix/solution to the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to get the log from gdebi. It just says that the dependency cannot be met. But installing libssl1.0.0 will fix it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

An updated version of RStudio is [available](https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-xenial-1.0.153-amd64.deb) for Ubuntu 16.04+ and Debian 9+ (both 64-bit only) on their [download page](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/).

Using this version, installation runs smoothly with `sudo gdebi rstudio-xenial-1.1.350-amd64.deb` on Debian 9.1. :)

Comment: This is indeed working on Debian, and seems the most straightforward answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Answer:

1. Install `libgstreamer0.10-0` & `libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0` [according to the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413323/rstudio-install-on-ubuntu-16-10-fails-due-to-libgstreamer/43586708#43586708)
2. `cd` into the directory with the rstudio deb file and Run (replace XXX with package version):

   ```
   dpkg --ignore-depends=libssl1.0.0 -i rstudio-1.0.XXX-amd64.deb
   ```
3. Run (replace nano with your editor if you feel like it):

   ```
   sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
4. Find the rstudio entry and delete `libssl1.0.0` from the `Depends: ...` line
5. Enjoy Rstudio

*References:*

[Ignore dependencies while installing](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/6i07ai/rstudio_on_debian_9_stretch/dj6p571/)

[Ingnore Broken Packages](http://www.sudo-juice.com/ignore-broken-packages-ubuntu-aptitude/)

Comment: I visited the link you left in the first point, but I did better following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44851086/2069269) (which is the currently accepted one, as I write this) than the one you suggested. I basically downloaded the preview R package, installed and then run it.

Comment: That is great. Preview didn't work yet when I wrote the answer. Or at least I failed to run it.